# Path integral quantization for scalar, spinor, and Yang-Mills gauge fields on a general differentiable manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, path-integral, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Most of the recommendations on path integrals on differentiable manifolds I've found here (like Kleinert) focus only on formulating quantum mechanics via path integrals on differentiable manifolds. Are there any resources which deal with path integral quantization of scalar, spinor, and Yang-Mills gauge fields on a general differentiable manifold?